# Total POIs in a country or for every category

Tags: google-places-api

Not really a technical question but they don't have other means of contact apart from https://groups.google.com/group/google-places-api and SO.

I'd like to get the total count of all POIs or the total amount of POIs in a category on a country. Is this possible in the API (since it always returns 20 results at a time)? if not, is there a google places support email to ask them about certain questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on [Places API Google Group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-places-api):

> Google does not disclose such information. However, If you are
>   familiar with a few places and locations in Thailand, you or your
>   client could simply perform a few searched on maps.google.com and
>   compare the results with your own knowledge to get a general
>   understanding of how precise or complete the data is.